# Run ajax listener action when choosing value from autofill list

Tags: javascript, jsf, event-handling, richfaces, autofill

I use jsf + richfaces + jboss seam. I have code :

```
<h:inputText id="receiptAmount" style="text-align: right;"
                    value="#{receiptsHome.instance.receiptAmountString}"
                    onkeypress="if((event.which &lt; 48 &amp;&amp; event.which != 8 &amp;&amp; event.which != 26 &amp;&amp; event.which != 44 &amp;&amp; event.which != 46) || (event.which != 127 &amp;&amp; event.which &gt; 57)) return false;">
                    <a:support event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true"
                        reRender="receiptAmount1, listContractsDiv"
                        action="#{receiptsHome.setPaymentMoneyForListContracts}" />
                </h:inputText>
```

But when i work on chrome. I have 2 case as below :

Case 1 : I enter number from keyboard with values : 20000. It run action in a:support tag and reRender red text at right. It's ok :
[image: input from keyboard]

Case 2 : I does not use keyboard. I use mouse to click from autofill list with similar values : 20000 (browser has save old that value before). It's not run action in a:support tag :
[image]

How can i choose from autofill list,it's still run action ?

Answer (score 2):

modern browser support `oninput` (not sure if `a4j` is supporting this event) which will be fired for both cases: If a key is pressed or if a autocomplete entry is choosen.

If you don't want to rely on this, use `autocomplete="off"` on the input element. (However I believe some browsers are ignoring this).

If you don't need the data to be processed after each keystroke, the best option would be to use `onblur`, because no matter if it was typing or an autocomplete selection, there will be a `blur` event once the input element looses focus again.

Comment: it's not a matter of a4j:support supporting it, h:inputText doesn't support the event in the first place